# Define vars before executing a powershell command in a runspace

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

At the moment, I have a simple function that execute a batch file in a powershell from C# using runspace and pipelines. This works fine but this batch file execute a .exe. However, I need to be able to cancel the command and cancelling the batch file doesn't cancel the exe.

My batch file just init 2 vars needed by the soft and then execute the exe command, returning the code returned by the exe.

My batch file looks like this:

```
set EVOLPATH=...
set CTLIBPATH=...
set path=%EVOLPATH%;%CTLIBPATH%;%UGII_ROOT_DIR%
C:\path\to\my\file.exe %*
exit %errorlevel%
```

Here is a simplified version of my c# code

```
Runspace _runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
_runSpace.Open();
String _command = "..."
Pipeline _pipePwShell = _runSpace.CreatePipeline(_command);
_pipePwShell.Input.Close();
_pipePwShell.InvokeAsync();
Boolean _end = false;
while (!_end)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
          _pipePwShell.StopAsync();
          _end = true;
    }
    if (_pipePwShell.Output.Count > 0)
    {
          Int32 _returnCode = Convert.ToInt32(_pipePwShell.Output.Read().ToString());
    }
}
```

The current code works fine, it start the .bat and kill it if canceled, but killing the .bat doesn't kill the .exe started which is my problem.

Which lead to my question: If I need to execute my first 3 lines that assign variables before running the .exe, how should I do:

Will it be enough to add commands in the pipeline and execute them ?

I don't really understand what runspace and pipelines really are and I don't find really clear explanations. Based on the name I would assume that the runspace will create a "context" where I will be able to assign my vars and then run the .exe without losing the vars ?

When I try to do it step by step in a powershell, the exe won't run because the vars aren't assign in the same "context".